# Renaming a start menu Item in Windows 10

Tags: windows, start-menu, windows-10-preview

In Windows 10, how can I rename a Start Menu Item?

In Windows 7, I could click on the start menu, then right-click on "All Program" and I would get a menu that popped up saying "Open All Users" and then a Windows Explorer windows would open up with all my start menu items and I could rename them to whatever I wish. How do I do this in Windows 10?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Right click the Start menu tile/item you wish to rename and click `More` ► `Open file location`. This will open the Start menu folder - typically something like `C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` - containing the shortcuts for all the menu items. You can then rename any of the shortcuts to your liking.

Comment: There is no "Open file location" option when right-clicking the tiles in Windows 10.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 there is for me. Under "More" as this answer states.

Comment: I would just like to add that, in the rare case you want to change the first letter from capitalized to normal, or vice versa, you first need to name it to something else before you can do this. This is due to the way Windows handles filenames

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

Answer (score 0):

If you hit Win+R and enter %AppData%, from the folder that opens, you can then search for Start Menu and manually edit items in your file manager. Likewise with %ProgramData%.

Answer (score 0):

On the "Open File Location", when you right click the item you'll see a selection item titled "more"; hover on this and a menu will open showing the "Open File Location" selection.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to rename Microsoft Edge tiles is to "Open File Location" for any third party app, make a desktop shortcut for the website, and then copy and paste the shortcut into the Start Menu/Programs folder that you opened in the first step.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rename an app downloaded from the Microsoft Store. However, you can rename any tile that you downloaded externally (eg. on the web). To do this, right click on the application's tile and go to `More` > `Open file location`. This will open a File Explorer window with a path that should look similar to this:`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. You can now edit any of the shortcuts in this folder to change the tile display name.

Comment: This isn't working for me... maybe a different path for items installed for "All users" instead of just me?

Comment: Also try <sysdrive>:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

Answer (score 0):

To open the Start Menu shortcuts folder you can open "Run", write "shell:start menu" and hit Enter. Then you can rename the shortcut you want to rename or add another one. However this still didn't do the trick for me, so if the name doesn't change try right-clicking the shortcut, go to "Properties" and change the "Comment:" property with the new name, this did it for me.