# Make the left pane of the Windows 10 start menu wider

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

The left pane in my Windows 10 start menu is too small. For example, I have the following two folder entries cut off:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 20..
Microsoft SQL Server 20..
```

(I can hover on start menu entries to see the full name, but that does not work for start menu folders which are *just* a little bit too long.)

**How can I make the left pane wider?** I can resize the start menu as a whole by dragging the right border, but that only increases the size available to the modern app tiles.

Comment: This is ridiculous. I reported this to MS in the very first Technical Preview back last year.

Comment: something http://superuser.com/questions/963168/can-i-increase-the-width-of-the-all-apps-section-of-windows-10s-start-menu# but not really helpful

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10, you *cannot* change the size of the left pane of the default start menu.

However, there is an application called [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) which can change your user interface back to the older windows 7 style, where you can resize all the parts of your start menu. It also changes windows Explorer to the Windows 7 style.

[image]

If you don't want to bother to install anything, go to Windows Explorer, and go to the Start Menu folder:

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`

and go to Properties.. of the application(s) whose name is too long and uncheck the read only option. Then, go to the **Privacy** tab and give your user full access to the folder. finally, you can rename it as per your liking. I hope this solves your problem.

Source:
[Renaming a start menu Item in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/932892/renaming-a-start-menu-item-in-windows-10)