# Can I increase the width of the All Apps section of Windows 10's Start Menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

The default width of the All Apps section is so small that several similarly named folders are not discernible any more. Is there a way to make it wider?

The new start menu is so buggy and lacks functionality anyway, I probably need to switch to an alternative, but I want to find out all configuration possibilities there are before I decide.

[image: Start Menu width too small]

Answer (score 2):

Set `MouseHoverTime` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse` to `8` you'll see a mouse hover tip immediately on entries that exceed the menu width.

I found the workaround above [here](http://www.tenforums.com/customization/19748-needing-start-menu-width-adjustment-all-apps.html).

I set my time to 100 and works nice; nevertheless, it only work on Shortcuts not on folders so, it may not help as much.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to use "Classic Shell". And complain it to microsoft so it can be fixed earlier.

After changing "MouseHoverTime", you still need to hover on every entry to see full text which is rather tricky. And you changed the global behavior of mouse hover time which may not be desired.

Comment: For guidance on how to recommend software in your answer, please see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers